# Entity Framework 4.3 default filtering on child collection

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Say I have the following set up:

```
public interface IBaseEntity
{
    bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}

public class Sushi : IBaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Fish> Fishes { get; set; }
}

public class Fish : IBaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And for auditing reasons, I can only flag rows as deleted but not actually removing them from the Db.

How can I tell EF that when I call `sushi.Fishes`, I only get the records that have `IsDeleted = false`?

In the current set up, **EVERY POCO** is inheriting from IBaseEntity, so I can ensure that the `IsDeleted` flag exist in all tables.

(I am using EF 4.3.1.0, unfortunately this cannot be updated at the time...)

Comment: Look into using global/context filters: http://www.agile-code.com/blog/entity-framework-code-first-applying-global-filters/